# Div with a curved side and overflow:hidden in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what Im trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/ShKNu/5/

As you can see, the map div is loaded on top of the `main` div, but the `overflow:hidden` only works in Firefox and IE. In Chrome and Safari, the map is not cut off, and overlaps into the `header` div.

- Firefox: Works
- IE: Works
- Chrome: Doesn't work
- Safari: Doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` breaks in webkit based browsers when the parent is not positioned statically, but that doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: @Enigmadan that's because google maps doesn't support rounded corners in V3; coupled with the common issue you've described above, Webkit browser will have a difficult time resolving this. Also, beyond that, I believe it's also against the google maps API terms of service to attempt to obscure any portion of the map element.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ah.  So would [this](http://www.driveu.com/) go against the ToS?

Comment: So does that mean I should stay away from this? It is something that would have to work throughout all platforms..

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this are you looking for?

```
.main {
display:block;
background: #999;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
margin-top: -30px;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 30px 30px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 30px 30px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 30px 30px 0 0;
}
```